# var x = x || "default val" not getting set properly if x is defined above it

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = "overriden";
</script>
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

**myjs.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = x || "default val";
  alert(x); // this alerts "default val" and not "overriden"
});
```

For some reason, `x` is ending up as `"default val"` and not `"overriden"`, even tho initially I'm setting it to `"overriden"` before I even include the script reference to myjs.js.

Any idea as to why this is happening?  I'm trying to enable the hosting page to set an override for a variable that's used in an included js file, otherwise use the default val.

Comment: maybe removing `var` keyword of first declaration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have after variable declaration hoisting is applied:

```
var x;
x = 5;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var x;
    x = x || "default";
});
```

It looks at the closest `x` and sees it's value is `undefined` which is a falsy value, so `x` gets set to `"default"`.

---

You would be fine if they were in the same scope, because the declarations are always hoisted above assignments so:

```
var x = 5;

var x = x || "default";
```

Is actually just

```
var x;

x = 5;
x = x || "default";
```

---

This was suggested which is completely pointless:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    x = x || "default";
});
```

It will throw a `ReferenceError` if `x` is not defined.

---

So either do the check in the same scope or do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = window.x || "default";
});
```

Invalid property reads don't cause a `ReferenceError` but just return `undefined` instead.

Comment: marking this as answer because several other answers suggested `var y = x || "default"` which you mentioned "It will throw a ReferenceError if x is not defined."

Answer (score 4):

The `var x` in the function passed to `$(document).ready()` is hiding the global scope `x` variable.

If you just use `x = x || "default val";`, then the global variable is clobbered. However, it's really a bad idea to have global variables at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `var` keyword in both places. Try:

```
x = x || "default val";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

From the above link:

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function
>   or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which
>   is bound to the global object).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are again declaring a new `var x` inside `document.ready()` which is another scope than global. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  x = x || "default val";
  alert(x); // this will now alert "overriden"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not defined in the scope of the `document ready` function.

`var x` is preparing the variable with the value `undefined`, so it won't get it from the window scope.

Try `var x = x || window.x || "default val";` instead.

Comment: x will give reference error if I do not define it that first time, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have it stated with a var that does not get the globally defined object from the html. Try removing the var and see if you get a different result, or change the variable within the function to a different letter.

When you use var within a function the scope of that var is only to the function. Since you have defined the x variable twice when you are doing the comparison it is attempting to use the variable from within the function.

If you plan to keep the var statement you will need to change the variable name or how you are calling the global `x` to `window.x`. The other option is just to drop the var from the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` created on this line:

```
var x = x || "default val";
```

...is local to the function it is defined in (i.e. it [shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `x`) .

Removing the preceding `var` will cause both `x` names to reference the same global variable, but this is generally a bad idea. From the previously-linked Wikipedia page:

> This can lead to confusion, as it may be unclear which variable
>   subsequent uses of the shadowed variable name refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `var x` in your function which creates local storage for `x` and hides previous values.

Call it `var y`, or do as karim79 suggested.

Comment: I really want to accept this one, but, if I do var `y = x || "default"`, then js throws an error saying that x is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var x` in the second one is local to that function, and isn't the same as  `window.x` (which is what you've defined in the former block).

Answer (score 0):

the keyword var means that you've just created a local variable. So basically what is happening is that:

1. You declare (in your first block ) x as "overridden"

Memory:

```
 x -> "overriden"
```

1. You set the callback to document.ready

Memory:

```
 x -> "overriden"
```

(after the document is loaded) 3. you run your anonymous function, initialising x with var

Memory:

```
x->"overriden"
[IN SCOPE]
anonymous_function.x -> "default_value"
[/SCOPE]
```

---

**"BUT WAIT"**, you might say, "the code I wrote is `var x= x || "default var"` so what should happen is `local_x=global_x || "default value` ,right?

Unfourtunately Javascript doesn't work like that. In javascript, we have function scope, instead of the more widely used block scope. So when you write:

```
f=function(){
    var x=y || "default value";
    var y=3;
    alert(x);
}
```

what'll be interpreted in javascript is :

```
f=function(){
    var x;
    var y;
    x=y || "default value";
    y=3;
    alert(x);
}
```

so running `y=10; f();` will give you "default value" on the prompt.

---

So taking off your `var` will work to fix your problem here, but just remember in general that all your variable declarations are done "at the beginning" of a function, so scope is immediately changed when entering a function.